# Write a query to find the full name of the actor who has acted in the maximum number of movies

Tags: mysql, join, count, sql-order-by, sql-limit

My code is as seen below, but I'm not getting the desired answer, which is to get the full name of the actor whose done the maximum number of movies.

```
SELECT CONCAT(" ",actor.first_name,actor.last_name) AS Full_name 
FROM actor INNER JOIN film_actor ON actor.actor_id = film_actor.actor_id
GROUP BY actor.actor_id
ORDER BY count(film_actor.actor_id) DESC
LIMIT 2, 1;
```

[image]

Comment: What is wrong with the results you are getting?

Comment: No sample testcases passed. (0/1)

Testcase #1
Status
FailedExecution time
3.60s
CPU
0s
Memory
6MB
Description
Testcase failed! The solution's output doesn't match the expected output.
Evaluation logs Solution output
*************************** 1. row ***************************
 PENELOPE GUINESS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should do what you want, but you need to fix the `limit` clause. If youw want the one actor with most movies, then you need `limit 1` rather than `limit 2, 1`. The `concat()` in the `select` clause also needs to be fixed - you want the space *between* the names, not *before* them.

Another option is to use an aggregate subquery for sorting, which avoids aggregation in the outer query:

```
select concat(a.first_name, ' ', a.last_name) as full_name
from actor a
order by (select count(*) from film_actor fa where fa.actor_id = a.actor_id) desc
limit 1
```

Note that neither your query nor this one take in account the possibility of top ties. Your question does not specify that. If that's what needed here, then the strategy would be different - but it seems this is not what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

If you dont want to use inner query and use only joins , this is the answer :

```
SELECT concat(FIRST_NAME," ",LAST_NAME) as full_name FROM ACTOR A INNER JOIN FILM_ACTOR FA on A.ACTOR_ID=FA.ACTOR_ID GROUP BY (FA.ACTOR_ID) ORDER BY count(FA.FILM_ID) DESC LIMIT 1
```